# cbind makes values null in r

Tags: string, r, matrix

I'm using cbind to bring together a matrix of string and numerics, and it is returning all of the columns of numerics (except the first one) as NULL.  Here is sample code:

```
nums <- matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4),ncol=2)
strs <- list()
strs[1] <- 'row1'
strs[2] <- 'row2'
result <- cbind(strs,nums)

> result
     strs         
[1,] "row1" 1 NULL
[2,] "row2" 2 NULL
```

I'm obviously overlooking something simple.  Thanks for the help,

Comment: Do you have to use a list? If you use a vector (e.g. `c('row1', 'row2')`, everything works very well.

Comment: If you are stuck with the lists then try something like: `result <- data.frame(strs=unlist(strs),nums)`

Comment: Awesome -- I'll happily accept this as the answer if you write it as one @sebastian-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I think you're going about the problem in slightly the wrong way. `cbind` returns a matrix. One of the limitations of matrices is that all elements must be of the same type. This means your `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` will, when coerced into a matrix, become the highest level data type present (in this case character from `strs`) and become the equivalent of `c("1", "2", "3", "4")`.

I'm going to assume that you have a list `strs` with 2 elements and that what you actually want is a data.frame (which is able to hold different types).

In either case, let's convert `strs` into a character first:

```
strs2 <- unlist(strs)
[1] "row1" "row2"
```

Note that this is the same as if you'd created it via `c("row1", "row2")`.
Next, we'll create a data.frame:

```
result <- data.frame(strs2, nums)
  strs2 X1 X2
1 row1   1  3
2 row2   2  4
```

This is essentially the same solution that @thelatemail provided.

Answer (score 1):

Combining lists with `cbind()` can be problematic. I would do as sebastian-c said in the comments or use `unlist()` on `strs` first:

```
cbind(unlist(strs), nums)
```

Or just use `matrix()`:

```
matrix(c(strs, nums), ncol = 3)
```

If `nums` has a variable number of columns:

```
matrix(c(strs, nums), ncol = ncol(nums) + 1)
```